# Would a smart phone work on an alien planet?

Tags: technology

Assuming it has a full battery would a smart phone and some of its apps work on an alien planet? The environment on the planet is similar but not the same as Earth. In other words a human couldn't breath without equipment, but there are no significant differences in pressure. Would apps like a calendar, downloaded music, downloaded games work?

Comment: Depends on what is *in* that atmosphere. Sulfuric acid?

Comment: Good point. The atmosphere is close enough to Earth for there not to be significant amounts of sulfuric acid.

Comment: Recharging it could be a problem though ...

Comment: iphones are allergic to helium: https://www.ifixit.com/News/11986/iphones-are-allergic-to-helium

Comment: Recharging it would be an issue. It's something I've had to integrate into my story.

Comment: @AvengingEarth Good question, just keep in mind that providing more details initially, as well as some requirements or criteria is beneficial. Questions that are too open ended can be tough for people to answer and evaluate.

Comment: Why would it _not?_ Bit of a strange question given the fact that you said the pressure is similar to Earth. It's not like phones draw power from the air...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes. A modern smart phone will work fine in a non breathable atmosphere, from vacuum to about double Earth pressure. Anything that doesn't need an internet connection or GPS will work.

eg [Samsung S9 is IP68](https://www.samsung.com/sg/support/mobile-devices/is-samsung-galaxy-s9-and-s9-plus-waterproo). This means 8 hours of 1atm pressure difference no dust can get in, and 1.5m of water none gets in over half an hour.

If the atmosphere is corrosive, the phone will corrode, but itll take a long time to loose functionality. Smears on the screen and metallic paint on the back dripping off will be the first signs.

Note that the touch screen may not work through a space suits gloves. You may need to enable the extra sensitive touch screen function before you get there.

In a vacuum it will eventually overheat. It will slow down and turn off rather than be permanently damaged. You wont be able to fast charge it in a vacuum either (unless you rest the phone on a big solid cold thing to stop the waste heat pulling the Li Ion battery above the critical 45 degree max temperature.). A very slow charge may work.

Microphone and speakers obviously wont work in a vacuum. Sounds may be slightly distorted in a different atmosphere to earth but should be recognisable as the original.

Many apps that allow downloaded content will auto-lock after a period without an internet connection. Eg Amazon Prime will block downloads after 48 hours offline.

Edit: Apparently helium can turn a cpu oscillator off. I didnt know that, but that would be something to watch out for. Not a lot of helium at ground level on many nearby planets, and most modern phones are watertight, but still a risk of tiny helium getting in.

Comment: *"Note that the touch screen may not work through a space suits gloves":* Use a Galaxy Note with its S-Pen.

Comment: Assuming the atmosphere isn't corrosive or such, overheating in vacuum was the other thing that came to mind. If you're prepared, though, you could bring an alternate heat sink better designed for the conditions. Such solution will probably be much bulkier, though. OTOH, if you don't mind the phone being tethered to you[r atmosphere suit], you could use liquid cooling and either use the device as an additional heat source or use the same cooling systems as for your body (depending if you need to add or remove heat).

Comment: @Matthew Phones are surprisingly corrosion resistant. There are videos of people putting phones in acid and other things, they can survive at full functionality for a decent while. Eg https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3xyICmQHy8

Comment: What is your reasoning for why it would overheat in a vacuum, and couldn't be charged in one? It seems like the only thing it would lose is convective heat transfer with atmosphere, it could still cool by conductive heat transfer or radiative heat transfer. So it would still cool, but not as fast.

Comment: @Mathaddict it will overheat. Phones will often overheat while charging without the ability to cool down. A smartphone on a medium speed charge is pulling 10-20 watts over the cable, and wasting about 2-4 watts in heat. That is a lot, the phone needs to get to about 90 degrees to radiate that much power in equilibrium. You can't charge Li-Ion above 45.

Comment: @Ash but why can't it cool down? You seem to think that convective heat transfer is the only way it happens while completely ignoring radiative and conductive methods of cooling.

Comment: I just calculated radiative transfer in my previous comment, it needs 90 degrees to radiate enough heat. Also yes I guess you could charge it if you attached it to a big heatsink for it to conduct into, but back along only the cable, no way. A 50 or 60 degree phone will scold the hands so you can't conduct through you while using it.

Comment: @Ash:  That it might overheat in a vacuum is no barrier to charging.  You plug in the charger, charge until it reaches the heat limit, then unplug it and let things cool down.  Repeat until fully charged.

Comment: " You wont be able to charge it in a vacuum either." — why?

Comment: @Mołot it heats up. A charger at 2.5amps is basically a 4 watt heater. It will heat up to 90 degrees before it's radiating enough heat. The cable can't conduct heat out fast enough to make a difference. A hand in gloves is 37 degrees and has its own heat problems, so is no help. When a Li Ion battery gets above 45 degrees C it can't charge anymore.

Comment: More than just the local atmosphere matters. For example, high levels of radiation could cause a smartphone to fail.

Comment: Certain other features might fail.  E.g. The compass won't work if the planet lacks a strong magnetic field.  Obviously maps won't work without a GPS signal.  The orientation sensor may fail if the gravity is significantly lower than Earth's.  (These are already a problem on ships in orbit in zero-G.)  Lack of atmosphere will also make the microphone and speaker useless.

Comment: Small amounts of helium will shut down many phones.

Comment: I don't think this should be a hard yes, or at least should have a big ol' caveat. As @Matt said, the radiation (or hopefully lack of) is a key factor. Most processors sent into space have larger feature sets than our best manufacturing can produce for exactly this reason. Radiation will cause far too many errors for a modern phone to be useful. If you have an old Nokia on the other hand...

Comment: re: Helium can throw a CPU off; not entirely accurate, it throws off the crystal oscillator. There is a great video going into the details here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvzWaVvB908

Comment: Also, watertight is different than Helium tight. Helium molecules are smaller than water molecules, therefore where water is stopped there is a chance Helium will go through. There has been a case where a Helium leak in a hospital, harmless for humans, blocked all the smartphones; I am not able to retrieve the news though.

Comment: @Matt If there is enough radiation to kill your phone in a few days, there's enough radiation to kill you.

Comment: @WaterMolecule Well if there isnt any oxygen you arent going to live very long either. Clearly a human operator is using some kind of equipment to survive in the environment. Anyway the question says nothing about other parts of the environment being human safe. This answer addresses a corrosive atmosphere, which probably isnt great for humans either.

Answer (score 5):

It would likely generally work, with the obvious exception that it would not have connectivity. There would be a few caveats.

Some phones, particularly iPhones, use a MEMS oscillator to run the processor. This depends on the atmosphere. Notably, a helium atmosphere prevents them from running, but does not damage them permanently. This can even happen on Earth if there is a helium leak, such as [in this hospital](https://9to5mac.com/2018/10/31/helium-bricks-iphone-apple-watch/).

High temperatures, even if not high enough to permanently damage the phone, may cause it to shut down. This can happen on earth if you have a phone mount in front of a heater vent. Similar situations may happen in vacuum or very thin atmospheres if the phone is not able to cool itself from the heat it produces.

Finally, vacuum may cause components in the phone to release gasses that don't form in an atmosphere. I'm not familiar with the effects, but I would expect it to cause weakening of adhesives (screen falling off) or fogging of the screen or camera.

In conclusion, there are a lot of possible issues, but it is not unreasonable for a modern smartphone to function outside of Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: the main concern id have with outgassing from comonents is failure of electircal components e.g. insulators failing leading to a short circuit or capitors changing capcitance or failing altogether, either could be pretty catastophic for the phone

Answer (score 1):

We have sent probes to orbit other planets of our solar system, and in some cases they have even landed on their surfaces.

The most famous cases are probably the probes which have moved on the surface of Mars, like for example [Curiosity](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap200306.html).

[image: Mars panorama from Curiosity]

Considering the sheer amount of information they have managed to send to us thanks to even simpler electronic than what we have today in a smartphone, I am sure apps which do not require connection to the internet would work fine.

Comment: The fact that some devices that are specifically designed to work on other planets do work on other planets is not evidence that smartphones designed for earth's environment would likewise work.

Comment: Also note, that simpler devices will usually tend to work better than complicated ones (except specifically designed ones for this purpose), because there are less components that may fail the entire design.